# Create a new Object on Json after click (http.put)

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I have the following json structure:

```
"disputas": [
    {
      id: "",
      tipo_negociacao: "",
      historico:{
         fl_usuario: "",
         created_at: "",
         updated_at: "",
         created_by: null,
         updated_by: null,
         texto: "",
      }
    }
]
```

I am updating this json using `http.put`, I want to create another object of `historico` each time I click on a button, so it would look like this:

```
"disputas": [
    {
      id: "",
      tipo_negociacao: "",
      historico:{
         fl_usuario: "",
         created_at: "",
         updated_at: "",
         created_by: null,
         updated_by: null,
         texto: "",
      },
         historico:{
         fl_usuario: "",
         created_at: "",
         updated_at: "",
         created_by: null,
         updated_by: null,
         texto: "",
      }
    }
]
```

How can I do this?

This is my service:

```
url: string = 'http://localhost:3004/disputa';
constructor(private http: Http){}
atualizaDisputa (body:Object): Observable<DisputaPropostaComponent[]>{
    let bodyString = JSON.stringify(body); // Stringify payload
    let headers      = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }); // ... Set content type to JSON
    let options       = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); // Create a request option
    return this.http.put(`${this.url}/${body['id']}`, body, options) // ...using post request
                     .map((res:Response) => res.json()) // ...and calling .json() on the response to return data
                     .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Ocorreu um erro em nosso servidor, tente novamente mais tarde')); //...errors if any
}
```

Thanks in advance. Let me know if you guys need more code.

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  You want to create something that looks like:  historico:{
         fl_usuario: "",
         created_at: "",
         updated_at: "",
         created_by: null,
         updated_by: null,
         texto: "",
      } 

when a button is pressed?

Comment: I've just edited the question, I think it's a little more clear now

Comment: You can't have two keys named historico on an object. You'll need to turn that into an array. Once you do that you can just push onto the array as usual.

Comment: Oh yes, that's right. Sorry, I've got confused. I'll do it with array. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have two keys named historico on an object. You'll need to turn that into an array. Once you do that you can just push onto the array as usual.